# Show that the set of Lorentz boosts in the $x$ direction, represented by the matrices $Λ$, form a group under successive application

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, matrix-elements

So the following question has been causing me problems. Show that the set of Lorentz boosts in the $x$ direction, represented by the matrices $Λ$, form a group under successive application

$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}\hat {ct} \\ \hat x\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{\cosh \varphi} & {-\sinh \varphi}  \\ {-\sinh \varphi} & {\cosh \varphi}\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{ct} \\ x\end{array}\right]
=Λ(\varphi)\left[\begin{array}{cccc}{ct} \\ x\end{array}\right]
$$

My original attempt: So under successive application would imply matrix multiplication.

For this set to be a group, the properties of Closure, Associativity, Existence
of Identity, and Existence of Inverse must be satisfied.

**Closure**: If $Λ_1$ and $Λ_2$ are members of the set, then $Λ_1^TgΛ_1 = g$ and $Λ_2^TgΛ_2 = g$

Then: $(Λ_1Λ_2)^Tg(Λ_1Λ_2)=(Λ_1^TΛ_2^T)g(Λ_1Λ_2)$ = $Λ_2^T(Λ_1^TgΛ_1)Λ_2 = Λ_2^TgΛ_2 = g$

**Associativity**: Matrix multiplication is known to be associative

**Existence of Identity**:

$$
I=\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 \end{array}\right]$$

is a member of the set, because $I^TgI = Ig = g$

**Existence of Inverse**: If $Λ$ is an element of the set, $Λ^T
gΛ = g$ by definition.
To show that the matrix inverse $Λ^{-1}$ also belongs to the set, multiply both
sides by $(Λ^{-1})^T$ on the left and by $Λ^{-1}$ on the right:

which yields $g = (Λ^{−1})^TgΛ^{-1}$

Hence the four properties are satisfied.

**Potential Error Found**: I realised that I have made an error as $Λ_1^TgΛ_1 = g$ and $Λ_2^TgΛ_2 = g$ are not true for the given matrix.

Could someone perhaps explain how I could fix my error and prove the required axioms are satisfied.

Comment: There is a mistake in your proof of closure.
Correct is $(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2)^T=\Lambda_2^T\Lambda_1^T$,
not $=\Lambda_1^T\Lambda_2^T$.

Comment: Oh yeah, I see that now. Is the rest correct?

Comment: For closure (and all the rest) you are thinking awfully abstractly in my opinion. Just multiply out two boost matrices with $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ and use   the “addition formulas” for hyperbolic cosine and sine. To get an inverse replace $\varphi$ with $-\varphi$. To get an identity set $\varphi=0$. The idea here is to show you the mathematical similarities to *rotations*.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: I dunno why you're doing such a convoluted thing with the inverse.  Existence of inverse means there is $\Lambda(\phi')$ so that $\Lambda(\phi')\Lambda(\phi)=\Lambda(\phi)\Lambda(\phi')=$ identity.  Cleary the $\phi'$ with this property is $\phi'=0-\phi$.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback.  I’m aware of that method also but I was just trying out new methods of proving the existence of the inverse. I’m trying to improve my understanding of these topics by experimenting with new ways of proving the axioms hold.

Answer (score 2):

For closure (and all the rest) you are thinking awfully abstractly in my opinion. Just multiply out two boost matrices with $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ and use   the “addition formulas” for hyperbolic cosine and sine. To get an inverse replace $\varphi$ with $-\varphi$. To get an identity set $\varphi=0$. The idea here is to show you the concrete mathematical similarities to *rotations*.

By the way, this *is* just a rotation matrix... through an imaginary angle! But don’t read too much into that. It’s a great memory aid, however.